# Polymer Styling Child Components

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to style my child components. Isit wrong to put the style in a parent component? It appears that does not work.

I put the style for `.card-page` in the top level element (containing `expenses-module` where I use it)

```
<dom-module id="expenses-app">
  <template>
    <style>
    ...
    .card-page {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
    </style>

    <app-drawer-layout>
      <app-header-layout>
        ...

        <iron-pages selected="{{routeData.view}}" attr-for-selected="name">
          <dashboard-module name="dashboard" route="{{subroute}}"></dashboard-module>
          <expenses-module name="expenses" route="{{subroute}}"></expenses-module>
          <settings-module name="settings" route="{{subroute}}"></settings-module>
        </iron-pages>
      </app-header-layout>
    </app-drawer-layout>
  </template>
```

In expenses module,

```
<paper-card heading="Expenses" class="card-page">...
</paper-card>
```

Seems like if I move the styles into `expenses-module` it works.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot directly style elements inside custom element from their parents like that, because Polymer processes the style within `<dom-module>` and will apply styles only to direct child members. It will not descend into child custom elements.

In other words, standard CSS selectors will only work within the scope of the declaring component. Both in Shadow and Shady DOM.

For your styles to work with nested elements, you should use [CSS mixins and properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#xscope-styling). All PolymerElements and many 3rd party elements will come with such styling extension points. The naming usually follow the convention, where the main mixin is called same as the element itself. Additionally, there may be more specific mixins and properties, which style only parts of the element. [`<paper-card>` docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-card#styling) for example lists `--paper-card` mixin, `--paper-card-content` mixin, `--paper-card-header-color` and more.

If you want to better control the styling of elements you use, you would want to create your own CSS mixins/properties and `@apply()` them to selected elements. See how in the example below `--my-elem-card-page` applies only to one of the two paper cards.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/> 
  <link href="paper-card/paper-card.html" rel="import"/>
</head>

<body>
  <my-wrapper></my-wrapper>
  
  <dom-module id="my-elem">
    <template>
      <style>
        .card-page {
          @apply(--my-elem-card-page);
        }
      </style>
      
      <paper-card heading="my-elem specific style" class="card-page">
        <div class="card-content">
          Content here
        </div>
      </paper-card>
      <paper-card heading="Default style" class="unstyled-page">
        <div class="card-content">
          Content here
        </div>
      </paper-card>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  
  <dom-module id="my-wrapper">
    <template>
      <style>
        # will be ignored
        paper-card {
          width: 200px;
        }
        
        my-elem{
          --paper-card: {
            color: blue;
            display: block;
          }
        }
        
        my-elem {
          --my-elem-card-page: {
              color: red;
          }
        }
      </style>
      
      <my-elem></my-elem>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-elem'
    });

    Polymer({
      is: 'my-wrapper'
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```